# pgfplots: bar chart | multiple addplot | centered to tick | labels of second addplot are missing

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

- I have a `xbar chart` in `pgfolots`.
- I want to have multiple `addplot` commands.
- I use `symbolic y coords` and `ytick = data`.
- **Problem 1** is that I want all **bars centered** in respect to the **`ytick`**.
- **Problem 2** is that the **labels** of the **second `addplot`** are **missing**.
- **Background:** I want this special layout because I want to have `nodes near coords` later in the `addplot` command (only for specific bars).

---

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    symbolic y coords = {A,B,C,D,E},
    enlarge y limits = 0.15,
    ytick = data,
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 10,
    title = {One \texttt{\textbackslash addplot}},
    ]
\addplot[fill=green] coordinates {(1,A) (2,B) (3,C) (4,D) (9,E)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    symbolic y coords = {A,B,C,D,E},
    enlarge y limits = 0.15,
    ytick = data,
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 10,
    title = {Two \texttt{\textbackslash addplot}},
    ]
\addplot[fill=green] coordinates {(1,A) (2,B)}; % A-B
\addplot[fill=green] coordinates {(3,C) (4,D) (9,E)}; % C-E
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: to problem  1: use `bar shift=0pt,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple to solve ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width = 160mm,
        height = 120mm,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 10,
        enlarge y limits = 0.15,
        symbolic y coords = {A,B,C,D,E},
%        % this only uses the data of the *first* `\addplot' command, but you don't
%        % need it at all in this case
%        ytick=data,
%        % in case the `ytick's haven't a Delta of 1 you could do either use
%        ytick={A,...,E},
        % ... or set the tick distance to 1
        ytick distance=1,
        title = {Two \texttt{\textbackslash addplot} and remove \texttt{ytick = data} but increase \texttt{height = 120mm}},
        xbar,
        bar shift=0pt, % --> added
    ]
        \addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(1,A) (2,B)}; % A-B
        \addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(3,C) (4,D) (9,E)}; % C-E

        % to add some stuff at coordinates in between the symbolic coordinates
        % use the `nomalized' option
        \node [circle,fill=red,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,pin={$1.5$}]
            at (axis cs:6,{[normalized]1.5}) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: In the actual use case I tried this (remove `ytick=data`) but then some labels were repeated. I try if I can generate a MWE. **Edit** When you increase the `height = 190mm,` then you see the problem I mean.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, this should be impossible. If you really could achieve that, you most probably have found another bug ;) Please let me/us know. But if it *is* a bug, you could also directly report it at the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/).

Comment: I edited the question. I have trouble at the moment with my account on SF.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Specifying the ticks explicitly is a way around that, e.g. for this case `ytick={A,...,E}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks (it wirks). I do not understand how the ticks work with symbolic ticks (what internal number is A or B for example) ;).

Comment: Also the `A` gets missing in the edited code in the question.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, I incorporated Torbjørn's as well as another solution to my answer to fix the problem with showing each entry more than one time or not all of them. Of course this could happen, but I normally don't use `symbolic coords` but use them indirectly using `ticklabels` to show there "text". To answer your second question: Internally each symbolic coord internally is an integer number starting from 0. To access "other"/normal coordinates on a "symbolic" axis you could e.g. say `\fill (axis cs:6,{[normalized]1.5}) circle (2pt) coordinate [pin={$1.5$}];`.

Comment: Thanks. Would you consider it a bug or normal behaviour?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, this is absolutely normal behavior.

Comment: Ok. Also the disappearing? Going to bed now :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, you mean the last `tikzpicture` in your edited question? There nothing is disappeared. Only the lower part of the graph is missing (scroll down until you see the axis). At least for me it is showing a bar at A ... Can you confirm this?

Comment: You are right! The gif export cropped it because the third page was larger than the other two. My mistake.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, not a problem. Then good night! ;)